# .NET Regex Equivalent of Python Regex's (?P=previousmatchname)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In Python's implementation of regular expressions you can do the following:

```
 <(?P<foo>.*)>(.*)</(?P=foo)>
```

and basically it will look for  `<this>right here</this>` but not `<this>right </here>`. Basically it allows you to use the previously captured named match later in your regex. Is there a way to do this with .NET's Regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sharp brackets or single quotes and use \k to reference them:

```
<(?<foo>.*)>(.*)</(\k<foo>)>
```

or

```
<(?'foo'.*)>(.*)</(\k'foo')>
```

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) page for more info and scroll down to the "Named Capture with .NET’s System.Text.RegularExpressions" section.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. For some reason the (\k<name>) part is not very well documented and doesn't show up in any of the references I googled.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<(?<foo>.*)>(.*)</\<foo>>
```